# I am not able to write a file in NFS which has some chinese character in file name

Tags: django, python-3.x, nfs

Basically, when user uploads the file I am writing that file into NFS. But it gives an error 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 28-32: ordinal not in range(128)

I have tried to install Chinese locale and set it but it is not working

I am taking the file name as this but it is not working

```
file_name = file_name.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
```

Comment: I've found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20) that could be useful for you!

Comment: Ascii does not support Chinese. You to use Unicode (utf-8).

Answer (score 0):

We were having the same issue on our Debian 11 server running Apache2. Our environment locale was UTF-8 but when testing it showed up on the browser as ASCII.

In our case, the solution was to change the /etc/apache2/envvars file and remove the # before . /etc/default/locale.

We found this solution at [itekblog.com/ascii-codec-cant-encode-characters-in-position/](https://itekblog.com/ascii-codec-cant-encode-characters-in-position/)